# Create a sublist from a list by comparing its elements in paire wise using recursion

Tags: c

Create a sublist from a list by comparing its elements in paire wise and choosing the minimum of the two in the new list (sublist).
Example : we have a list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] the output should be a sublist such as [1, 3, 5] since min(1,2) = 1 and min(3,4)=3 and min(5,6)=5.

```
void pairWiseMinimumInNewList_Rec(Node* head, Node* cur_list_dest, Node** head_dest)
{   
    /* There must be at-least two nodes in the list */
    if (head != NULL && head->pt_next != NULL) 
    { 
        /* Treatement */

        if (head->val < head->pt_next->val) 
            if (head_dest==NULL)   //if (!head_dest)
               {
                *head_dest=head;
                cur_list_dest=head;
                cur_list_dest->val=head->val;
               }
             else
               {
                cur_list_dest->pt_next=head;
                cur_list_dest=head;
                cur_list_dest->val=head->val;
               }            
         else
             if (!head_dest) 
               {
                *head_dest=head->pt_next;
                cur_list_dest=head->pt_next;
                cur_list_dest->val=head->pt_next->val;
               }
             else
               {
                cur_list_dest->pt_next=head->pt_next;
                cur_list_dest=head->pt_next;
                cur_list_dest->val=head->pt_next->val;
               }        
    }
 
        /* Call pairWiseMinimumInNewList() for rest of the list */
        pairWiseMinimumInNewList_Rec(head->pt_next->pt_next, cur_list_dest, head_dest);    
}
```

I can't write the recursive processing in C. This is my recursive program that doesn't work. how to transform it if possible into a void function.

Thanks for anyone who can help.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are asking for help with?

Comment: Examples of sample input and output would be useful.

Comment: Please add the recursive code you came up with. We will help you fix it, but we won't be making it from scratch for you

Comment: There's no good reason to use recursion for this. Is it a requirement of the assignment?

Comment: the OP wrote a recursive version and added an example. The question should be reopened